# Geodesic on the catenoid , how to determine arc length curve equation

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

In the following question

> [Geodesic on the catenoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048978/geodesic-on-the-catenoid)

We have in the answer, an arclength parametrization on a particular Catenoid that is given by :
$(u'(t))^2+cosh^2(u(t))(v'(t))^2=1$

(Considering we parametrize the catenoid by $r(u,v)=(cosh(u)cos(v),cosh(u)sin(v),u)$)

My question is what principle or formula is used to determine such an arc lenght curve expression ,

To be more precise , what i want is to find expression of the "curve that generates the surface of revolution when turning it around an axis ",  and i guess it has to be arc lenght parametrized to be able to apply Eulers equation and minimize the related integral ,

Comment: For the fun: http://touch-geometry.karazin.ua/m/catenoid-with-geodesic-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "what i want is to find expression of the 'curve that generates the surface of revolution when turning it around an axis' "

Look at your parameterization $r(u,v)$. If you think about how those coordinates describe the geometry of the catenoid, taking $v=\text{constant}$ will give you a curve that will generate a catenoid as a surface of revolution. Taking $v=0$, it is easy to see that the function $x(z) = \cosh z$ will suffice.

> "My question is what principle or formula is used to determine such an arc length curve expression"

If you have some curve $\gamma(t)$ in a Riemannian space with metric $g$, you can find the arclength $s$ of the curve at any time $T$ as

$$s(T) = \int_{t_0}^{T}\|\vec{v}\|dt$$ where $\vec{v} = \gamma '(t)$. This becomes clear using the notion that distance traveled equals the integral of the speed with respect to time. Using a tensor formulation, we will say that the length of the velocity vector is $$\|\vec{v}\| = \sqrt{g_{ij} v^i v^j }$$ thus

$$s(T) = \int_{t_0}^{T} \sqrt{g_{ij} v^i v^j } dt \text{ .}$$

We can reparametrize $\gamma(t)$ as $\gamma(s) = \gamma(T(s))$ by integrating and inverting $s(T)$.

> "Geodesic on the catenoid , how to determine arc length curve equation"

Use the geodesic equation as parameterized by arclength. The geodesic equation is a statement that the second derivative of the position with respect to arclength equals zero. It reads as

$$ \frac{d^2 x^k}{ds^2} + \Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{dx^i}{ds} \frac{dx^j}{ds} = 0 $$

which is (in general) a system of coupled, second order, ordinary differential equations. Here $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ is the Christoffel symbol which are the connection coefficients for this geometry. Solutions to the geodesic equation will, by nature, be parameterized with respect to arclength.