# Give Clairaut's relation for a Catenoid and explain how you find it

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, geodesic

I'm interested in finding geodesics of particular revolution surfaces,

I've not studied "Clairaut theorem" or "Clairaut's relation" in course ,

However, a relation is given on Wikipedia :

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation

I have to say that for the moment I don't really understand how to easily extract Clairaut's relation from a particular parametrization of a surface of revolution, so let's choose the example of the cathenoid, with a choosen parametrization
$$(r,\theta)\rightarrow (\cosh(r)\cos(\theta),\cosh(r)\sin(\theta),r).$$

On a question I link, the author says the translation from the Clairaut's relation would be
$$\cosh(r)^2 \dot \theta \equiv c$$

> [Geodesic on the catenoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048978/geodesic-on-the-catenoid)

However I don't really understand how to find it trivially.

Comment: Please show your first steps in your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not giving here how Clairaut's Law is found. Consult any text book on differential geometry for it.

You are not supposed to find general laws from particular situations.

A way to find geodesics on a catenoid is given here by application of this law.

Angle $ \psi$ is between meridian and geodesic, $\phi$ is slope; Using cylindrical coordinates for catenoid $ (r,\theta,z);$  In cartesian coordinates $z$ is from $r= c \cosh \frac{z}{c},$ and $ (x,y)= ( r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) $.

Clairaut's Law:  At $ r=r_{min}$ geodesics are tangential.

$$  r^2 \frac{d \theta}{ds}=r \sin \psi = r _{min} \tag1 $$

$$ \cot \psi= \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{r_{min}^2}-1} \tag2$$

Draw a differential triangle in tangent plane

$$ \frac{dr}{\sin \phi }= r \;d \theta \;cot \psi \tag 3 $$

Meridian of minimum catenoid radius $r=c$.

$$ r =c \cosh {\frac{z}{c}}; \; \tan \phi =\frac{dr}{dz} =\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{c^2}-1}\tag 4 $$

Eliminate $(\phi,\psi)$ combining all these and integrate to get polar projection/ view of the geodesic:

$$ \frac{dr}{d \theta}= \frac{\sqrt{(r^2-r_{min}^2) (r^2-c^2)}}{r_{min}}. \tag 5$$

$r_{min}$ can be greater,less or equal to $c$. There would be two or one cover of geodesics.

[image]